# PDF file in iframe overlapping top navigation menu on IE 11

Tags: html, css, wordpress, pdf, iframe

I am using iframe to display PDF file for my wordpress portal. 
This is the iframe code:

`<iframe src="pdf file URL" width="800" height="800"</iframe>`

File displays correctly on Chrome and Firefox browser. But on IE 11 browser, it overlaps on the top navigation menu. Please check this screenshot.

[PDF iframe overlapping issue on IE11 browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLqv3.jpg)

This issue is only for PDF file.

Comment: May be give a Margin-top to the iframe

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340820/pdf-embed-not-working-in-ie11-but-it-works-when-edit-the-html-in-dom-explorer to resolve it

Comment: Thanks...but not found the solution. PDF file displays but it overlaps on the menu. Overlapping is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried z-index: -1000; in the css?

Comment: what about margin-top: 100px; in the css?

Answer (score -1):

include meta tag with charset=utf-8 in header.php after

Comment: can you share your html for that page??