# Not able to embed PDF blob in HTML in IE

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have adopted various approaches to embed PDF blob in html in IE in order to display it.

1) creating a object URL and passing it to the embed or iframe tag. This works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

```
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
    <iframe id="test_iframe" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></iframe>
    <script>
        function previewFile() {
            var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            console.log(downloadUrl);
            var element = document.getElementById('test_iframe');
            element.setAttribute('src',downloadUrl);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

2) I have also tried wrapping the URL Blob inside a encodeURIcomponent()

Any pointers on how I can approach to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDF embed not working in IE11, but it WORKS when edit the HTML in DOM Explorer (F12 - debug tool of IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340820/pdf-embed-not-working-in-ie11-but-it-works-when-edit-the-html-in-dom-explorer)

Comment: I have already tried it. It is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support iframe with data url as src attribute. You could check it in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). It shows that the support is limited to images and linked resources like CSS or JS in IE. Please also check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc848897(v=vs.85)):

> Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or
>   attributes.
>
> - object (images only)
> - img
> - input type=image
> - link
> - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background,    backgroundImage, and so on.

Besides, IE doesn't have PDF viewer embeded, so you can't display PDFs directly in IE 11. You can only use [msSaveOrOpenBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh772332(v=vs.85)) to handle blobs in IE, then choose to open or save the PDF file:

```
if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    //IE11
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobData, fileName); 
}
else{
   //Other browsers
    window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    ...
}
```